# Full quality emoticons in textbox of wpf application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am building sms application what should use emoticons into text box.

I have full quality imgs which are clickable to add code of specific emoticon.

xaml button of emoticon:

```
<Button Height="32" Width="32" Margin="171,448,99,119" Name="emoO" Click="emoO_Click">
    <Button.Template>
         <ControlTemplate>
              <Image Source="Emoticons\1f631.png"/>
         </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Code behind emoO button

```
private void emoO_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        txtMessage.Text = txtMessage.Text + WebUtility.UrlDecode("%F0%9F%98%B1");
    }
```

Is there any chance to get into txtMessage emoticon in full quality as original image?

[image: Text box]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display images in TextBlock (WPF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727248/display-images-in-textblock-wpf)

Comment: @LeonardoSeccia well, How do I decode image into unicode string then?

Comment: Read the answer marked as accepted answer... It explains it well...